# Wiring up Ajax.BeginForm that didn't exist during doc.ready?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery, unobtrusive-ajax

I have a MVC page that loads a Partial via a Ajax.ActionLink, which works, and then the loaded Partial contains a form that has Ajax.BeginForm.  This form is not getting wired up to unobtrusive ajax, and instead is performing a page refresh(I verified this in the Network log of the browser that shows the initiator when I click submit is the browser instead of jquery).

What I believe is the issue is that since the form didn't exist when the page is loaded(but later is added via the Ajax.ActionLink), then unobtrusive ajax didn't see the data-ajax attributes on the newly added form and wire up the necessary events.  I'm assuming that only happens at document.ready, and the ajax form didn't exist then.

**Is there something I can do to say "hey Unobstrusive Ajax, please look at my page again now that I have some new elements that are marked with data-ajax and wire them up"?**

Thanks.

Looking at the unobtrusive ajax source, it has this:

```
$("form[data-ajax=true]").live("submit", function (evt) {
        var clickInfo = $(this).data(data_click) || [];
        evt.preventDefault();
...
```

The form tag generated looks like this:

```
<form action="/Path/Create" class="form-horizontal" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#ParentContainer" id="PathForm" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

As far as I can tell the selector on the .live event should be picking up on the new form when it's loaded onto the page.  The form is inside a bootstrap modal however, so I don't know if that would be preventing the event from bubbling up somehow.

I can even run this in Chrome console:

```
 $("form[data-ajax=true]").live("submit", function (evt) {
            var clickInfo = $(this).data(data_click) || [];
            evt.preventDefault(); });
```

And it returns the form element successfully, but when I click submit it still does a full page refresh.  I would expect it to at least do nothign since I wired it up to preventDefault.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? .live is deprecated as of 1.7

Comment: 1.8, the unobtrusive ajax file is a MS file though with no version number.  I tried an experiment with .on, running this before the dynamic form was added to the page, and it still didn't prevent the form submit from refreshing page, we think nested forms are the cause: `$(document).on("submit", "form[data-ajax=true]", function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault(); return false });`

Comment: can you put your entire source code in jsfiddle or something like that so I can see what the entire code looks like or close to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question regarding unobtrusive ajax and dynamically loaded content, **it should work fine out of the box.  The way it wires up to events with .live(deprecated, still works *currently*) should detect forms that are loaded dynamically onto the page.**  So apparently it doesn't suffer the same problem that unobtrusive validation does.

Our problem was unrelated to that.  We were using bootstrap modal which spawned a modal div from inside a form.  Since the modal then loaded another page containing a form, we realized we had a form within a form (even though it didn't really look that way since the other form was in a modal).

To solve this we moved the declaration of the modal div in the first form outside of the form.  We could still have a link that referenced the modal to show it, but not the modal's inner form wouldn't be nested in the first form.

I believe the reason this caused both the .live and .on methods to not catch the event was because they depend on the event to bubble up to the document, and it bubbled up only as far as the outer form which was not an ajax form, thus did not match the selector.

Another solution would have been to write .on more like this so that the event would be caught when it bubbled up to the container of the inner form, instead of scoping it to the document where the event would reach the outer form first.

```
$('#innerModalId').on("submit", "form[data-ajax=true]", function (evt) {
   evt.preventDefault(); 
   ...
   return false 
});
```

However since this was part of a library, that's not an ideal solution as I would have needed to repeat their code.  We didn't get as far as updating unobtrusive ajax:
http://nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Ajax.Unobtrusive

But I think we would have still had the problem since even with .on it still didn't work due to our page structure problem.